# Changing the View for a Doc Lib Web Part

Tags: document-library

We have a SharePoint page with a Document Library Web Part .    We would like to put a drop down menu on the site which can be used to easily change the view of the document library.    We have three different views defined "By Project", "By Process" and "By Type".    How can we change the view using a javascript or jquery function ?

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past to accomplish something similar is to use a jquery tabs solutions. Take a look [HERE](http://www.bitsofsharepoint.com/ExamplePoint/Site/TabPage.aspx)

Using this method you will add 3 document library web parts, one for each view. Place the document library web parts in the tabs provided. The tabs are really several web part zones, each wrapped within a div in a page layout. Then the solution uses javascript to hide or show the div that users select from the tabs.